# expression for if condition where i used both parameter and field values in with in if condition

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have written an expression like below ,but it is showing some error ,can any one help me with this....

=IIf(Parameters!Plan.Value=="all",IIf(Fields!Plan.Value=="freedom",count(Fields!No_Of_Admissions.Value),0), 0)

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [This.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786212/how-to-use-multiple-conditions-with-and-in-iif-expressions-in-ssrs)

Without much detail I'm thinking you want to do something like this.

```
=IIF(Parameters!Plan.Value="all" AND Fields!Plan.Value="freedom", count(Fields!No_Of_Admissions.Value),0)
```

Comment: thank you for your reply ..actually your expression is error free, but still  i am not getting the required result...

Comment: What is your goal for the expression?

Comment: Thank you ,now its giving result,,but as per my requirement      
  city          count

  delhi         23
  jaipur        6
  delhi         12
  delhi         3     here i want  sum(count) when city delhi selected        the result should be delhi=38